# Position in nested list under criterium

Tags: filtering

I start from the following exemplary list, e.g.,

```
list = {{1, 2, 2}, {3, 2, 4}, {3, 5, 2}, {4, 5, 6}, {2, 5, 6}, {2, 5, 
    2}};
```

I learned how to to pick out elements of a specific column that fulfill a certain criterion by

```
In:  Select[list, #[[3]] > 2 &]
Out: {{3, 2, 4}, {4, 5, 6}, {2, 5, 6}}
```

Now I want to have the values and positions in the original list. I tried something like

```
In: Flatten[Position[list, _?(#[[3]] > 2 &)]]
Out: {2, 4, 5}
```

which actually gives me what I want, however with some error messages

```
"Part specification List[[3]] is longer than depth of object."
```

What is the correct way to do the pattern matching with `Position`? Certainly, I could ignore the error messages with `Quiet`.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

```
Flatten[Position[list, _?(#[[3]] > 2 &), 1, Heads -> False]]
```

> {2, 4, 5}

Comment: Are you still using v9? Do you have any ideas for [this problem](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41406465#41406465)?

Comment: @Szabolcs, still on v9:(

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Position[list, {x_, y_, z_} /; z > 2] // Flatten

(*  {2, 4, 5}  *)
```

Have fun!